# ASP.NET Core Access Files inside subfolders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET with VSCode. I am new to ASP and this is my first project. I created the project and created a folder called `admin` with an `index.cshtml` file in it. But when I try to access the file in the browser by typing `localhost:5000/admin/`, `localhost:5000/admin/index` and `localhost:5000/admin/index.cshtml`, but none of these URLs display the WebPage. Instead the browser shows that the URL could not be found in localhost:5000.

I tried to find out a solution by Googling, but found nothing. I do not want to jump into MVC just yet, as I have never worked with it.

**PS:** Please don't get this removed with the reason that "This question needs more research." I am a beginner and have already explained what I could have.

Answer (score 1):

The way Asp.net MVC framework works is:

- Request first goes to an action and not a view (e.g. `index.cshtml`). Of course a lot happens before that
- Folder name is **by default** mapped with the name of an existing controller. So you need to have a controller named `AdminController` that will have to be inherited from a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`
- In the `admincontroller` controller you need to have an action called `Index`
- Then your `index.cshtml` needs to be put either in the `/Views/Admin/index.cshtml` location or in the `/Views/Shared/index.cshtml` location

After that when you hit the Url `localhost:5000/admin/index` the request will go to the Action called `Index` in the `AdminController` controller. The last line of an action method is usually `return View();` which will look for a cshtml page named that matches the name of the action. Which is `Index` in this case. So it will start to look for a `index.cshtml` file. That is how it will render your `index.cshtml` view if it is found.

Here a simple controller and action:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public AdminController()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Conventional routing typically used with controllers and views.You must create your views in the right location.In general, if you want to return a view for a controller action, then you need to create a subfolder in the Views folder with the same name as your controller. Within the subfolder, you must create a view with the same name as the controller action.

You can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/overview/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs) to understand what is mvc.

If you are using ASP.NET,you can try to create a AdminController in Controllers folder like this:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you are using ASP.NET Core MVC,you can try to create a AdminController in Controllers folder like this:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
    {
    
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```